# c# run console application as different user... impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, web-applications, impersonation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Process.Start() impersonation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936456/process-start-impersonation-problem)

I am trying to run a console application as a different user in c#, but I am having trouble. Here is part of my code:

```
public void encryptPGP(string fileName)
{
    string sCommandLine = "" +
                "--recipient \"User Name <username@domain.com>\" --encrypt \"" + fileName + "\"";

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Utilities\\GnuPG\\App\\gpg.exe", sCommandLine);
}
```

... I need to have the C:\Utilities\GnuPG\App\gpg.exe ran by a certain user. How would I add that in?

This will be used in a web application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` class to provide user credentials under which you want to start the process. See sample code below :

```
string userPwd = "secretPassword";
System.Security.SecureString pwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in userPwd.ToCharArray())
{
    pwd.AppendChar(c);
}

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo inf = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
inf.FileName="path to file";
inf.Domain = "domainname";
inf.UserName = "desired_user_name";
inf.Password = pwd;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(inf);
```

I personally have not tested this solution, but it should work framework 2.0 onward.

Hope it helps you.