# How to start powershell process with impersonate ImpersonationLevel?

Tags: c#, powershell, security, com, impersonation

I have to set `RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE` to powershell process. Do you have any idea how i can achieve this ?

I've only found [this](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/CoInitializeSecurity.html) info. It's about Changing the Default Impersonation Levels Using C++ via `CoInitializeSecurity`. But unfortunately I can't use it for `powershell`. It's required having a `main` function.

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// Do not set STAThread since CoInitializeSecurity is called 
/// with to high security automatically (and it can only be called once).
/// </summary>
//[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    // Set threading apartment
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA; 
    CoInitializeSecurity( IntPtr.Zero, -1, IntPtr.Zero,
        IntPtr.Zero,RpcAuthnLevel.None ,
        RpcImpLevel.Impersonate,IntPtr.Zero, EoAuthnCap.None, IntPtr.Zero ); 

    Application.MainForm = new MainForm();
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Application.MainForm);
}
```

I have a client(`powershell`) and service. I can't call service because it gives me following error:

```
Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.
```

And I found in `*.log` that current impersonation level is `Identification`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It's very unclear with your current code.

Comment: i have a win service. i try to connect to this service via rpc by powershell(with current account which is admin). but unfortunately security context of powershell process has wrong impersonation level(Identification). I need different impersonation level - impersonate. Do you have any idea how i can start powershell process with different impersonation level ?

Comment: What do you mean `service via rpc by powershell`?

Comment: [This question might be useful for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936456/process-start-impersonation-problem)

Comment: run powershell as admin under current account and try to connect to win service which is also on the same machine

Comment: If you didn't launch the current process as admin, you can't force powershell to run as admin, it goes against the elevation model.

Comment: i just go to win+r and start powershell.exe as admin